# ESS and R from spacemacs

Tags: r, emacs, ess, spacemacs

I hope this isn't a really dumb question, but I've used emacs in the past with ESS to edit R files and run them in an R process. I'd like to do the same with spacemacs. As far as I can read and grasp, it just means I have to enable the ess layer in the .spacemacs file, and that's it.

So in my .spacemacs I have the following:

```
'(
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; auto-completion
     ;; better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     ;; git
     markdown
     javascript
     colors
     haskell
     c-c++
     ess
     html
     ;; org
     ;; (shell :variables
     ;;        shell-default-height 30
     ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
     ;; spell-checking
     ;; syntax-checking
     ;; version-control
     )
```

But if I close spacemacs then, and reboot, and try to create say an R file, there's no ess or formatting/colours or anything like that. The same for something like markdown too. All files are just opened in Fundamental mode. I thought spacemacs had layers so you can just add them and it work out of the box. So what am I missing or what should I check? I'm on OSX.

Thanks,
Ben.

Comment: Is anything from your .spacemacs file executed?  What about list files?  Can you manually execute it and get the desired behavior?

Comment: Instead of manually closing and reopening spacemacs, you can refresh the config file by `SPC f e R`. Also, restart is `SPC q R`.

Comment: An equally dumb question: Did you remove the `.emacs` file from your $HOME? It will be easier if you move __everything__ of the pre-spacemacs into a backup directory and install spacemacs.

Comment: Came here with exactly this problem. `SPC f e R` worked, but I needed to kill and revisit the R file for it to work.